# Change the label on authors in elsarticle class document

Tags: elsarticle

The labels on authors in a elsarticle class document are alphabetical, is there a way to change it into numerics ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is certainly possible, but is it wise to do so? The letters refer to the addresses immediately below the authors, whereas author footnotes (generated by `\fnref` and `\fntext`) are labelled numerically and appear at the bottom of the page. If you number everything then it is not clear where to search for the note.